# Colors appear in the ui at any time

Tags: material-ui

[Layout with colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCRdK.jpg) Different colors appear in different parts of the layouts, also when passing the mouse.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you are trying to solve.